# How to delete single item from realtime Firebase in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

can someone help me how I can make to delete a single item from realtime database  using remove() function following this code? It say's that 'id' is not defined
Thanks )

```
import { expensesRef } from '../firebase';

const ExpenseItem = (props) => {

    const handleDeleteExpense = (id) => {
        
        expensesRef.child(`expenses/` + id).remove();
    };

    return (
        <li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
            {props.name}
            <div>
                <span class='badge badge-success mr-3'>{props.priority}</span>
                <span class='badge badge-info mr-3'>{props.cost} Lei</span>
                <TiDelete size='1.5em' onClick={handleDeleteExpense(`${id}`)} />
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};

export default ExpenseItem;
```

[image: Here is how my database looks]

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of explanation, I'm going to remove the `handleDeleteExpense` function from your code, leaving it with:

```js
const ExpenseItem = (props) => {
    return (
        <li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
            {props.name}
            <div>
                <span class='badge badge-success mr-3'>{props.priority}</span>
                <span class='badge badge-info mr-3'>{props.cost} Lei</span>
                <TiDelete size='1.5em' onClick={handleDeleteExpense(`${id}`)} />
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};
```

You see here that, the only spot referencing `id` is in the `TiDelete` component. Most likely, you intended `id` to be set by the parent component like you are doing for `name`, `priority` and `cost`. So you need to change `id` to `props.id`.

Then in the parent component, you'd add it using something similar to:

```js
const { name, priority, cost } = ref.val();
<ExpenseItem
  id=snapshot.key
  name=name
  priority=priority
  cost=cost
/>
```

or the shorter

```js
<ExpenseItem
  { ...snapshot.val() }
  id=snapshot.key
/>
```

It's important to note that the snapshot's key, not your id inside your data, is what is being passed through. If you used the other ID, the `handleDeleteExpense` isn't going to work.

Next, this line, will cause your data to be deleted as soon as your component renders because you are calling the function straight away:

```js
<TiDelete size='1.5em' onClick={handleDeleteExpense(`${id}`)} />
```

Instead it should be:

```js
<TiDelete size='1.5em' onClick={() => handleDeleteExpense(`${id}`)} />
```

You also import a reference called `expensesRef`, which I assume has been initialized with `firebase.database().child('expenses')`. This means your delete instruction is also deleting `expenses/expenses/<id>` instead of `expenses/<id>`.